# What routine tasks have to be performed on the outside of spaceships/stations?

Tags: space, space-travel

What kind of routine tasks have to be performed on the outside of spaceships or space stations? Repairs, I presume. Anything else?

Is there anything that needs to be cleaned off from the outside, like debris, or some other substance? Can anything on the surface freeze?

Comment: @DeerHunter: Hm. So just in theory, could you imagine something that would have to be removed from the outside in the future, even if only for aesthetic reasons? What if things get more crowded in space and debris becomes more common?

Comment: If you see a possible conjunction, you plan a DAM ([debris avoidance maneuver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debris_avoidance_maneuver)). Basically, anything that intersects your orbit may possibly penetrate the tinfoil-thin shell of the spacecraft.

Comment: Re: removal - aesthetic reasons aren't valid. Anything else is practical and possible (crew safety, craft survival, craft performance reasons).

Comment: This is not a physics question. It would however be suitable for http://space.stackexchange.com

Comment: @ChrisWhite - it is still in private beta. After a week, a lot of space questions are liable for migration.

Comment: One of the criticisms I've heard of the ISS is that it was poorly designed, so it requires an excessive amount of exterior maintenance by astronauts doing EVAs. This may be one of the reasons that the claims for the ISS as a platform for scientific research are almost completely bogus. ISS astronauts spend a huge amount of their time on tasks that are needed purely in order to stay alive.

Comment: @BenCrowell - mixing up correct and incorrect info. On maintenance tasks - correct, on external maintenance - incorrect (3 days IIRC for an EVA protocol isn't much), poorly designed - incorrect (cutting edge of **reliable** technology in both countries). The main burden of maintenance is in the sanitation & water reclamation system (also OGAs - oxygen generation assemblies). Add obligatory physical exercise to prevent deconditioning...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Space EVAs are performed to

1. repair stuff;
2. install new equipment;
3. inspect and photograph ship/station from the outside;
4. reconfigure electrical/hydraulic connections;
5. disassemble/disconnect existing equipment;
6. stow/unstow equipment when [remote manipulators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dextre) are unavailable;
7. [deploy and retrieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STS-7) (grab) satellites for repair (own sats)/perusal (alien/enemy sats);
8. conduct experiments (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expedition_5);
9. [claim priority](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexei_Leonov);
10. conduct ship-to-ship transfers in case of incompatible/malfunctioning [docking nodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low_Impact_Docking_System);
11. drop spanners [and other things](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pavel_Vinogradov) inadvertently...

Cleaning is not really something that's planned. Leaking ammonia/water from the cooling loops will usually evaporate. Any other water is recycled, solid residue is [lyophilized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyophilization), stored in bags and then dumped in cargo ships.

Aesthetic reasons aren't usually taken into account - see this picture of Zvezda Solar Arrays:

[image: ISS solar arrays]
Credit: NASA